# Словосочетание «обзор на»

Tags: стилистика

В последнее время всё чаще начинаю думать над тем, правильно ли вообще так говорить. Одни знакомые пытаются убедить меня в том, что это неправильно, аргументируя тем, что обзор может быть чего-то, а не на что-то. Знакомый филолог (который, между прочим, когда-то на этом форуме тоже сидел) говорит, что так говорить неправильно, а вот слово *рецензия* с предлогом *на* правомерно сочетается.

Почему допускается выражение *вид на...*? Здесь же сходное правило, нет? И опять непонятно: вид ведь может быть чего-либо и на что-нибудь. Итак, как всё-таки правильно говорить?

**P.S.** Употребление этого словосочетания меня интересует в следующем контексте:

Пользователь написал *обзор на игру*.
Или
Пользователь написал *обзор игры*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сравним два предложения:

(1) Здание с размещенной на нем конструкцией находится на одном из поворотов Кутузовского проспекта, поэтому до определенного момента водители машин в транспортном потоке, движущемся из центра, его просто не видят, зато потом **внезапно открывается обзор на огромную светящуюся установку,** находящуюся близко к земле на своеобразном постаменте.

(2) Бывает так, что наблюдение с господствующих высот **обеспечивает обзор на большую глубину**, но при этом сокращается **обзор близлежащих районов** и непосредственных подступов к высотам.

В предложении (1) выражение "обзор на" желательно заменить на выражение "вид на", а в предложении (2) "обзор на большую глубину" и "обзор прилежащих районов" кажутся правильными.

Скорее всего, **следует различать две формы:** обзор (чего? дополнение) и обзор (какой? определение). Дополнение задается только Р.п., а обстоятельственное определение - различными падежами.

Comment: Я бы определённо усмотрел ошибку в первом примере (недопустимый падеж дополнения) и счёл бы корректным второй (прямое дополнение просто опущено, подразумевается "обзор пространства"; "на" относится не к предмету обзора, а к его возможностям в техническом смысле).

Comment: Vera, употребление этого словосочетания меня интересует в другом контексте. Например, *пользователь написал обзор на игру*. Или *обзор игры*?

Comment: Согласно словарю, обзор в этом значении - это сжатое сообщение о связанных между собой фактах, событиях, явлениях и т.п. Библиографический о. О. художественных произведений. Сделать краткий о. международной обстановки. Но в настоящее время пользователи РАСШИРЯЮТ значение слова, например: обзор на игры, обзор на кукол, обзор на резиночки для плетения. Конкурируют две формы: описание/обзор игры (дополнение)  и обзор на игру (обзор на тему игры, тематический обзор, определение). Возможно, сказывается влияние английского выражения a review on the game.

Comment: Это значение, скорее всего, не зафиксировано в словарях, пока не нормировано, да и на слух непривычно. С другой стороны, с точки зрения грамматики, такая форма может существовать.

Comment: То есть это тоже правильно?

Comment: Форма достаточно активно осваивается пользователями, но для окончательного вывода о ее правильности она должна быть внесена в словари.

Comment: Я бы сказал, это на грани допустимого - не настолько катастрофично, как "список на комплектующие". Но такой подход подразумевает условность: выбор типа материала из формально предусмотренных в каком-то частном регламенте документов ("инструкция", "описание", плановый "обзор"). Как материал внутри программерской фирмы это пройдёт, как упоминание в печатном издании - вызывает сомнение.

Answer (score 2):

"Обзор на", по аналогии с "рецензией" возможен в словосочетании "обзор на тему", где слово "обзор" выражает форму информационного материала и полностью отвлечено от действия "обозревания". Если же это слово используется в прямом смысле "просмотра чего-то", оно сохраняет сильную связь со смыслом переходного глагола "обозревать (что)", от которого образовано. Например, техническое понятие "угол обзора (чего? - пространства)". Поэтому в таком контексте я склонен присоединиться к аргументации в пользу "обзор чего".